# <Link> not working in <Button> for next.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

Trying to have a  wrapping around a  that I created in my Navbar as below shows:

```
  <NavBtn>
    <Link href="/contact" passHref>
      <Button>
        Contact Me
      </Button>
    </Link>
  </NavBtn>
```

Here is my custom Button.js

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  height: 45px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #908db9;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  
  &:hover {
    background: #b8b4f0;
  }
`

const Button = ({ children }) => {
    return  <StyledButton><a onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}>{children}</a></StyledButton>
}
```

Basically, I cannot click the button like I normal behaviour. But I can't resolve where the issue is coming from :(

Please advise as I am a little lost in what I have done wrong. If need more information let me know!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Button within a link?

Comment: Just swapped Link and Button lol, can't believe I didn't try that yet. How do you make it so that when you hover over the button it'll respond as if it's clickable? As currently just only occurs when I hover over text

Comment: do you need write `onClick` in Link ?

Comment: Neither approach seems valid to me. You either have a button or a link. I don't understand what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried just having a button or a link alone, but it doesn't seem to click into the contact page if I try that. Sorry I'm just very new to this.

Comment: It seems like you want to get to another page, so use a link. If it is SPA, you should use router to get to the `/contact` url.

Comment: That's right, works now just lose my styles but that's not an issue. Thanks Mr T

Answer (score -2):

Just wrapped inside Extra Div it will solve the problem.
where  are using button component

Comment: thank you for answering on Stack Overlfow. To improve your answer, please add  example code of how your suggested solution works.

Comment: This is not a good solution, since wrapping with a div will cut out some accessibility features.